# Difference between this.user.id and this.user = {id: ....}

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I can't understand why the following code throws an error:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user',
  templateUrl: './user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user.component.css']
})
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
  user: {id: number, name: string};

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit()
  {
    this.user.id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.user.name = this.route.snapshot.params['name'];
    // this.user = {
    //   id: this.route.snapshot.params['id'],
    //   name: this.route.snapshot.params['name']
    // }

    console.log(this.user.id);
    console.log(this.user.name);
  }
}
```

```
ERROR TypeError: this.user is undefined
```

while

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user',
  templateUrl: './user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user.component.css']
})
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
  user: {id: number, name: string};

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit()
  {
    // this.user.id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    // this.user.name = this.route.snapshot.params['name'];
    this.user = {
      id: this.route.snapshot.params['id'],
      name: this.route.snapshot.params['name']
    }

    console.log(this.user.id);
    console.log(this.user.name);
  }
}
```

does not.

I don't really understand what's going on and why does it throw an error.

Isn't user a JSON object? If so, why can't I access it with this.user.id?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// This is a declaration, not initialization
// it just states that the class contains
// a reference to a user object with these two
// priorities
user: {id: number, name: string};
```

User is nothing (undefined) until you assign a value to it. In the second example you do it here:

```
// this syntax means creating an object with id and name properties
// and assigning to the user class member, which is at the moment undefined
this.user = {
      id: this.route.snapshot.params['id'],
      name: this.route.snapshot.params['name']
    }
```

Your first example fails here:

```
     // This syntax, assumes that the user is already
     // a defined object, and just tries to change the id value
     this.user.id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
```

You are trying to assign a value to the property of a non existent object.

Answer (score 3):

```
user: { id: number, name: string }; // This is only a declaration of a variable.

user; // same like this

// here it will throw error coz you are trying to
// access user object properties which does not exist.
this.user.id = 5;
this.user.name = 'John';
```

When we declare as well as initialize variable that error wouldn't appear.

```
 // declare with object reference and initial values
 user:{id: number, name: string} = {id: null, name: null}

 // or only initialization with default values
 user = { id: null, name: null }
```

Now if you access `id` or `name` and assign any value it won't throw error, coz it already know the user object properties.

```
this.user.id = 5;
this.user.name = 'John';
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I accepted the other one as correct though, because it was faster.

Answer (score 1):

In first variant it is not initialized and you try to set up a property of undefined object. That's why it throws an error.

In the second scenario you explicitly initialize a user variable with a new object value.